# Reinstalling Debian 10 and switching from the non-graphical install back to desktop environment

Tags: debian

Is it possible to reinstall debian 10 and switch back from non-graphical install back to the desktop environment so i can have the gui version

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
apt update
apt upgrade
reboot
```

After the reboot

```
tasksel install desktop gnome-desktop (or other desktop like mate)
```

You will need internet for downloading the packages.
Maybe read the following [page](https://linuxhint.com/install_gnome_debian_10_minimal_server/).

Comment: I tried that already but i dont have any packages thanks anyways

Comment: Excuse me? They will be downloaded. Did you setup your network configuration? Try "ping google.com" and see if you get an answer.

Comment: Temporary failure in name resolution

Comment: Then that is your next problem to solve. Do you have a modem or a router with dhcp?

Comment: yeah it does have it

Comment: If it worked, don't forget to accept the answer.

Comment: not really but is there any way to check if im connected to the internet since mine is pretty bad and maybe thats causing the problem

Comment: Login as root or use "sudo" and try "ifup eth0". Just a wild guess.

Comment: Unknown interface

Comment: https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration

Comment: will that still help if im on wifi?

Comment: It depends on many factors. Google (or duck.com) for "linux wifi tutorial" and see with which one you can work. But i forgot, how do you surf the internet if your box doesn't connect to it.

Comment: would it be possible to download a gui on a usb and somehow transfer it onto my computer?

Comment: If you have the original cds, they should be configured within your repos. You can try to insert disc 1 and run the command i provided. Sorry, but i'm prett much sure, that anything else will confuse you.

Comment: alright thanks i will see later what else i can do